# Promotion options not visible to Editor role

Tags: nodes, 9

I have a "Editor" Role with limited access rights. It can basically only create blog type nodes.

I'd like to expose to them the possibility to make to publish the node to the frontpage via the drupal core "publish to startpage" Promotion Option.

By which permission is this controlled? I tried all the node ones, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this is controled by the **administer content** permission. It has security implications, as it also exposes the ability to change the author and creation time of the node.

If you don't what that, you'd need to use the form_alter hook to dissable the athor and creation time field for the **Editor** role.

For example:

```php
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if (in_array('editor', Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles(), true)) {

    switch ($form_id) {
      case 'node_blog_edit_form':
      case 'node_blog_form':
         $form['author']['#access'] = false;
         break;
    }

  }
}
```